Which value can I get a hold of in an Expo app which is guaranteed to be unique for that app?
On an expo app, I need to get a hold of a value that would necessarily be unique for this app (not the instance, but the app itself).
For example - a bundle id could be it, as it will be the same for all instances and versions of that app on all devices it is installed on, but is unique for that app only.
My issue is that I can't find a way to get the bundle ID in expo.
react-native-device-info seems to be the only library that helps getting the bundle ID but I can't seem to find a way to make it work on expo.
Is there a different value that answers these demands which I can get a hold of in expo?
** It is ok if the value could be different between the iOs and Android versions of that app. Like bundle ID could be different. Ideally not- but it's ok.

To get a unique identifier for your Expo app, you can use the Constants.manifest.id or Constants.expoConfig.slug properties from the expo-constants module. These properties are consistent across different instances of the app and can serve as a unique identifier similar to a bundle ID. Thats is the quick example see it.
import Constants from 'expo-constants';

const appId = Constants.manifest.id || Constants.expoConfig.slug;
console.log("App ID:", appId);

This value should remain the same across all instances of your app, and while it might differ between iOS and Android, it is unique to your app and can be used as a reliable identifier. However, note that these properties are only available if your app is managed with Expo.
If you require more flexibility or need access to other properties like the bundle ID specifically, you may need to consider ejecting from the managed workflow to gain access to native code and libraries such as react-native-device-info.
If you need to other info related to this so please also check it hairfood   5

Thank you! I was hoping to get something that I'd be able to use both in expo and react native. Also, isn't slug only relevant for expo rather than for the app stores as well? Meaning the user could maybe use he same slug in different apps?
Regardless, I think that's what I'll end up doing as I don't think the exact solution I am looking for exists.
Thank you.
